# Run same jar file sequentially in a loop for different inputs

Tags: java, shell, jenkins

Am executing a jar file in remote server using jenkins job build step through publish over ssh.

Input build parameters for the job,say list - a,b,c,d,e

Execution command for publish over ssh -

```
cd /myjarfilepath

for input in $list
do

java -Xmx1024m -cp myApp.jar com.CommandLineRunner $input 
done
```

job fails with error 
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec timed out or was interrupted after 120,000 ms]

It runs successfully for one input. Say if it fails for input b then it gets terminated without executing the jar for c,d,e. I want execute the jar for all the inputs available.

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: try just putting an `echo` in front of your java line so it only echos the line. That would guarantee a very fast run. If this succeeds, you can assume it is truly some kind of a timeout and you know to pursue increasing some kind of threshold. If it fails, it may be that there is a bug or it can't properly handle your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is because of default timeout set to=120000. By updating transfers->Advanced->Exec Timeout(ms). I was able to build for all in loop successfully.
[image: Jenkins job build step]